# Converter Inteiro para Decimal em Oracle

Tags: sql, query, oracle

como faço para converter um número inteiro para decimal no oracle?

Hoje, a consulta saindo dessa forma.

> 75

Porém, eu quero que saia com 2 casas decimais, dessa maneira.

> 75,00

Segue abaixo a sintaxe da coluna.

```
select nvl(sum(ve.vl_vencimento),0) Valor_Total_da_Ordem from ordem_compra
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sempre utilizar a função `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(NVL(SUM(ve.vl_vencimento), 0), '999999D99') Valor_Total_da_Ordem 
FROM    ordem_compra
```

Comment: Obrigado @JoãoMartins, deu certo.

Comment: De nada! Aproveite e dê um UP na resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Se sua aplicação já tem tratativa baseada nos tipos do oracle, é possível fazer um type cast do campo desejado usando a função [CAST](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html)

```
select Cast(nvl(sum(ve.vl_vencimento),0) as DECIMAL(10,2)) Valor_Total_da_Ordem from ordem_compra
```